# Editing a value enclosed in a JAR File

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to edit a long value in a JAR file.

I tried using a Java decompiler, DJ Java Decompiler, and 7zip and modifying the .class file by creating a new file in Notepad++ and then copy + pasting the code that was decompiled. It says that the jar file is corrupted.

Shown below is the value that I am trying to change and I can't seem to change it successfully. Any help would be appreciated

[image: Image of value that I was trying to change]

Comment: Did you re-compile the file before putting it back into the jar?

Comment: Is this at all related to JavaScript?

Comment: @vlaz I would think not. I removed the tag.

Comment: Is the jar code signed?

Comment: Hello everyone I don't really know. I just google stuffs learned java for like 3 years ago and I forgot most of the things about it. Here is the link though. I uploaded it.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAYLtP2ShXjS25zbnNuYmkwWkk

from

http://www.neocodex.us/forum/topic/119879-tppc-general-auto-attacker-bot/

Comment: @kaitoy I uploaded it.. drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAYLtP2ShXjS25zbnNuYmkwWkk from neocodex.us/forum/topic/119879-tppc-general-auto-attacker-bo‌​t

Comment: seems not signed.

Comment: @kaitoy so what would I do? this has been bothering me for the whole day and I can't seem to find the way to decompile and then recompile it

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you dont have the source code with you and the Jar is Not Signed.

In that case, follow the below steps
1. open the class in a de-compiler
2. Save the class as Java file
3. Compile the java file and again convert it into class file.
4. Put the class file in the Jar

Comment: what decompiler? the decompiler above doesn't have a save as option

Comment: Generally you cannot edit your file when you are opening using any Archiver like 7zip. Does your jar contains fewer class files? If so then open all class files, save all class files to java file one by one. Finally create Jar.

Comment: I can't cause my decompiler won't save it as a .java file, let alone edit it. I'm using jd-gui-1.4.0 by the way.. DJ Java Decompiler expired because of trying too many things and getting it all wrong. Do you recommend any decompiler and editor I can use?

Comment: also, there are still files like .png and others.. in a separate folder.. how to do it..